# Postgresql: Updating with two inner joins [MySQL to PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

In MySQL it's possible to do something like this:

```
update 
    table_a A 
inner join 
    table_b B 
on 
    A.field_five = B.field_five
inner join 
    table_c C 
on 
    B.field_one = C.field_one and A.field_two = C.field_two
set A.field_three = C.field_four
```

I have tried to construct the same query in PostgreSQL like this:

```
update table_a A 
    set A.field_three = C.field_four
from table_b B  
    inner join table_c C 
on 
    B.agency_id = C.agency_id and A.field_two = C.field_two
where 
    A.field_five = B.field_five
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"

I'm using PostgreSQL 11. What is the correct way to do this query in postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't specify what table to update in "set" and move "A.field_two = C.field_two" to the where clause

```
update table_a A
    set field_three = C.field_four
from table_b B  
    inner join table_c C 
on 
    B.agency_id = C.agency_id 
where 
    A.field_five = B.field_five
    and A.field_two = C.field_two
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mipu88sd4JDar25TtvQCQJ/1

Answer (score 0):

Youl could rewrite it using CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c.*, b.field_five
  FROM table_b B  
  JOIN table_c C 
    ON B.agency_id = C.agency_id
)
UPDATE table_a A 
SET field_three = C.field_four
FROM cte c
WHERE A.field_five = c.field_five
  AND A.field_two = c.field_two;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=af4f3f8bd8bfb84af2a774742753ba89)**